# RabbitMQ direct exchange is not consuming messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, producer-consumer, rabbitmq-exchange

edit: edited to make it more generalized

I have a producer thread wanting to send a message to the consumer threads in Java using RabbitMQ direct exchange, but my consumer are not receiving the dish. Below is the method my producer uses to publish the message:

Note that `key` was passed as a parameter and was determined in a previous if-else statement to be either `"key1"` or `"key2"` string.

```
public void producerSend (Object object, String key) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    
    String exchange = "directExchange";
    
    System.out.println("PRODUCER: Sent message);
    
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    byte[] byteArray = getByteArray(object);
    try (Connection con = factory.newConnection()){
        Channel chan = con.createChannel();
        chan.exchangeDeclare (exchange, BuiltinExchangeType.DIRECT);
        chan.basicPublish(exchange, key, null, byteArray);
    }
}
```

Below is the method my consumers use to consume the message:

```
public void consumerReceive() throws IOException, TimeoutException  {
String exchange = "directExchange";
String key = "key1";
    
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    try (Connection con = factory.newConnection()) {  // added a try clause 
    Channel chan = con.createChannel();
   chan.exchangeDeclare(exchange, "direct"); // direct exchange
    
    String queueName = chan.queueDeclare().getQueue();  
    chan.queueBind(queueName, exchange, key); 
    
    
    chan.basicConsume(queueName, true, (x, msg)->{
    byte[] byteArray = msg.getBody();
    try {
        Object object = (Object) deserialize(byteArray);
        System.out.println("CONSUMER: Received message. Bye!");
       
        
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    }, x->{}
    );
    }
}
```

Note that I added a `try clause` when creating a new connection for the consumer as there were many consumers (threads) that are continuously created to order and obtain a message, and I want them to only connect ONCE with the producer to obtain the message, then stop connection (consumer says bye).

Before, when I did not add the `try clause`, so the consumers were able to receive the message and leave, but when the next consumer joins and waits for their message, the producer ends up sending the message to ALL of the consumers who had previously received their message because the connection was still open with the previous consumers. That's why I added the `try clause`, but I'm not sure why after adding it, the consumers no longer receive any dish (the consumer connection is not created?).

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me resolve this problem. I only want one unique consumer to receive each message and leave (close the connection with that consumer?)

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you close connection without waiting message. Nothing stop your code to close all and that's kill consumer thread that is launch.

So you need waiting in a while loop :

```
private static final volatile boolean NO_LEFT = true;    
    public void tamagoReceiveDish() throws IOException, TimeoutException  {
    String sushiDishEx = "sushiDishExchange";
    String tamagoKey = "tamagoDishKey";
    
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    try (Connection con = factory.newConnection()) {  // added a try clause 
    Channel chan = con.createChannel();
   chan.exchangeDeclare(sushiDishEx, "direct"); // direct exchange
    
    String queueName = chan.queueDeclare().getQueue();  
    chan.queueBind(queueName, sushiDishEx, tamagoKey); 
    
    
    chan.basicConsume(queueName, true, (x, msg)->{
    byte[] byteArray = msg.getBody();
    try {
        Sushi sushi = (Sushi) deserialize(byteArray);
        System.out.println("CUSTOMER " + this.custNo + " (ordered Tamago Sushi): Received " + sushi.sushiName + ".");
        System.out.println("CUSTOMER " + this.custNo + ": Left the restaurant.");
        NO_LEFT = false;
        
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    }, x->{}
    );
   while(NO_LEFT){
     Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    }}
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the response! i tried applying your suggestion to my code and it works, except the program does not allow me to declare "final" and "volatile" together for NO_LEFT. therefore i changed it to "private static volatile boolean NO_LEFT = true;" and added a "NO_LEFT = true;" after breaking out from the while loop, so that the next customer's connection will remain open and waiting to receive their sushi. it's working now. thank you so much for your help! have a great day :)

Comment: Yes NO_LEFT variable is not final, it is a mistake.